# it start but No DESKTOP

Tags: .desktop

as the title says after logging in I have the blue page. It connects to the network, responds to changes in brightness and volume, but no desktop. I have the version 18.04.4 lts. I tried to look in the faq and I tried some commands but I prefer to expose the problem here before doing other damages. Before logging in at the top right I could select between xubuntu, xfce and lxqt, this discovered trying to solve .. now I only have xubuntu and xfce. The PC is a Lenovo, atom processor z36xxx / z37xxx. The problem was born trying to lighten the system from some program but I have deleted something of important because after cleaning it was impossible for me to open any folders. I reinstalled the file managers, and on restarting the problem of the absence of the desktop occurred. Thank you all.

Comment: What did you delete and what did you install attempting to fix it?

Comment: hi, i dont remember exactly, delete something that need to open folders and reinstall same kind but of course different, like nautilus or something similar, unluckly i play since few time on ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` latter one is heavier. These packages install default packages on each comes at the beginning, hope this one helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Run `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.* great job man! i use ubuntu-desktop and now it work, i've in login page the possibility to choose between xfce, xubuntu, ubuntu, ubuntu on wayland. just ubuntu work. all fine. do you think that i need anything else to clean my system? thx very much